# create a list of files and folders inside of a folder via cmd and outputting it in a .txt

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I need to create a list of files that is in a certain folder, and then outputting it in a .txt file and put it on my desktop. Is this possible with CMD and if so, how can I do this?

Windows 7 Home premium 64bit

Comment: Powershell is not an option for you?

Comment: I never used Powershell before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dir/a/b/s path\to\folder > Desktop\files.txt
```

(Remove `/a` if you don't want to list "hidden" files.)

Alternatively,

```
tree/f > Desktop\files.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. tree/f is a shortcut to it?

Comment: @kb67: No, `tree` is a different program - it lists files in a pseudo-graphical tree view. (`tree` lists only directories, `tree/f` includes files.)

Comment: Which one would you prefer? :)

Comment: @kb67: It depends on which format _you_ want the list to be. Just run `tree` and `dir/a/b/s` and compare.

Comment: How do I specify the directory with tree

Comment: @kb67: Put it after the command, just like with `dir`. Example: `tree blah` or `tree/f blah`