# In Windows is there a way to get a list of all files and folders in a folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I need a list of all the files and folders in a folder. My end goal is to print out this list on paper. I don't want this to be recursive, so I don't need a list of the files in folders and the folder being searched. So for example there's folder name `foo` and it contains the files `bar` and `wombat` and a folder called `crazy` so I need the list to contain

- bar
- wombat
- crazy

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create a list of files and folders inside of a folder via cmd and outputting it in a .txt](http://superuser.com/questions/262417/create-a-list-of-files-and-folders-inside-of-a-folder-via-cmd-and-outputting-it), [Create file/folder list](http://superuser.com/questions/8755/create-file-folder-list) ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, from the Windows shell, you can direct the output of `dir` to a file like this:

```
dir > list.txt
```

which will give you the full directory listing.  And if you use the `/b` option, `dir` will just output the file and directory names, without the additional information:

```
dir /b > list2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, does this get hidden files and folders?

Comment: No. You need to use the /a:- option for a listing that includes hidden files and folders.  Use dir /? to see a list of options.

Answer (score 1):

`/B`     - Uses bare format (no heading information or summary)

`/A:-`   - displays files and folders with ***any*** attributes

`/O:G-N` - sort `G` - Group directories first, `-N` - reverse By name (alphabetic)

```
dir /B /A:- /O:G-N
```

Output:

```
bar
wombat
crazy
```

@Mox answer command:

```
dir /b
```

Output:

```
bar
crazy
wombat
```

@Mox answer command, if `wombat` set hidden attribute:

```
dir /b
```

Output:

```
bar
crazy
```

sample at `foo` folder and save output to `C:\mushroom.txt`

```
dir /B 'C:\foo' /A:- /O:G-N>C:\mushroom.txt
```

powershell alternative:

```
powershell ls -Fo^|sort Mode,Name -desc^|ft Name -Au -Hi
```

powershell alternative, file save:

```
powershell ls -Fo^|sort Mode,Name -desc^|ft Name -Au -Hi|more /E +1>C:\mushroom.txt
```

Comment: Please describe how this command works and how to run it.

Comment: In general, the mushroom in handy here) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EllYgcWmcAY

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force
```

Would get all items, including hidden and protected.

You can the use PowerShell commands to format the text however you wish:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force | Select-Object Name, Attributes, Extension, LastAccessTime
| Out-File "C:\Results.txt"
```

Which would look something like:

[image]

Comment: @AthomSfere `ls -Fo` short form `Get-ChildItem -Force` ...

Comment: @STTR yes, gci can also be used for Get-ChildItem, ls is the linux equivalent of dir too. I always use longform in scripts though for easy readability for me, new users and posterity.

Comment: @AthomSfere It seems to me that a simple, though not the right approach will win). And our perversions with powershell not wanted, that's sad. As a gift analogue `paste-d`: `powershell $f1=gc col1.txt;$f2=gc col2.txt;for($i=0;$i-lt$f1.length;++$i){$f1[$i]+$f2[$i]}>col-new1-2.txt`

Comment: Don't force it.