# how to get all subfolders in a folder in mac terminal?

Tags: macos

in mac terminal, is there a way to enumerate all subfolders in a folder? my goal is to do something inside every subfolders in a folder like this sudocode:

```
for subfolders in folder
    do something
end
```

here is the structure of folders

```
-folder 
    -subfolder1
    -subfolder2
    -subfolder3
```

this question is a bit similar to the question here [In Windows is there a way to get a list of all files and folders in a folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/610587/in-windows-is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-and-folders-in-a-folder), and i did not find the answer for macos.

many thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Use `for subfolders in folder/*/`; it will set `subfolder` to e.g. `folder/subfolder1/` (since the tailing `/` is part of the wildcard pattern, it'll be included in the results). See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352290/listing-only-directories-using-ls-in-bash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use several different shell commands to find the set of subfolders and then iterate over them to do something. I tend to use the [`find` command](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html), because it lets you set the criteria to match files or folders with a specific depth, exclude files/folders based on their type, name, date modified, and so on.

Keep in mind that iterating through a list of files while changing the items (e.g. renaming the subfolders) can lead to weird behaviour sometimes. Let's assume you're just doing some read-only operations in each directory to keep it simple.

```sh
% for dir in $(find "/path/to/folder" -depth 1 -type d); do
    cd $dir
    echo "Doing something in $dir..."
done
```

This `find` command matches files under the specified path with a depth of 1 (i.e. not searching for more than one level of subfolder) and type of `d` (directory). If you want all nested folders or to include files, you can change or remove these options. (By default `find` will search all depths and match both files and folders.)

Then inside the loop, `cd` switches to each directory in turn, and we're just using `echo` as a demo of what operation you might want to do inside each folder. (If you need the short name of the directory for an operation, you can use `basename $dir`.)

Note: because this script uses `cd`, it leaves your terminal in the last folder it found during the loop. If this was going into a script for real usage, you would either not use `cd`, or save the `$PWD` value prior to the loop and restore it afterwards.

Comment: I think you need a `cd ..` as the last line in the loop. Otherwise the `cd` in the 1st line of the loop will fail the 2nd time thru the loop.

Comment: `for dir in $(something)` will fail if any filenames (/dirnames) contain spaces, and on macOS lots of them will. Use a raw wildcard, or `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' dir` instead (see [BashFAQ #20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)). Also, `cd` in scripts always makes me nervous, because if anything goes wrong (or even you get confused about the navigation) the script'll wind up executing in the wrong place, which can have [disastrous results](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378942/cant-initialize-osx-interrogation-folder).